# Failed to load extension from . manifest file is missing or unreadable - no extension name

Tags: java, selenium, ubuntu, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run automated tests using Selenium Webdriver and webdrivermanager (bonigarcia). I am using Ubuntu + IntelliJ Idea.
For Firefox, driver is starting without any issues.
For Chrome I get the information:

> selenium webdriver failed to load extension from . manifest file is missing or unreadable

I am not getting any name of this extension here, so no idea what is the problem.

I already tried to uninstall, clear all caches, try on a different PC, etc.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for that issue was to change the type of Chromium browser. 
I have uninstalled Chromium which was in snap version and installed Chromium Web Driver. 
More info can be found here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075103/chromium-config-folder-is-missing-in-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 0):

I found that my problem was a dangling symlink to browswerpass, which I installed, and then uninstalled.

Answer (score -2):

Try to update chrome latest and bonigracia 3.4.0

Comment: I have just set up a new environment - new ubuntu 19.04 with chromium + I have bonigarcia exactly 3.4.0. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Check this out https://askubuntu.com/questions/872572/when-i-try-to-start-chrome-i-get-a-message-that-says-failed-to-load-extension-f